# Blur filter effect header

Tags: css

I am trying to make my header create a bluring effect. But clearly it is not working very well.

http://jsfiddle.net/3gd5t58o/2/

```
<div id="header"></div>
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/10.jpg" alt=" "/>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <filter id="blur"> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" /> </filter> </svg>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    clip: rect( top, offset of right clip from left side, offset of bottom from top, left);
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    filter: blur(20px);
    filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
}
```

Is there a easy way to make my header blur the content under it?

Comment: No. CSS cannot blur sibling elements; only child or self-contained elements. You'll need JS.

Comment: With canvas I imagine. Or can I use SVG?

Comment: I would blur it in photoshop (or on the server if it's a dynamic image) and then set the crispy version as the background of the element under the header and the blurry version as the background of the header and then find a way to keep them aligned (maybe background attachments or a combination of css and js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari 9+ has a CSS [backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop%20filter) feature just for this:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
```

Chrome supports `backdrop-filter: blur(3px);` if the Experimental Web Platform features flag is turned on.

See [this article](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/advanced-css-filters#backdrop-filter) (scroll down a page).

Comment: Do you know when chrome will support it without the need to activate Experimental Web Platform flag?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way (you need some position) :

```
<div id="header"><img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/10.jpg" alt=" "/></div>
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/10.jpg" alt=" "/>
```

Here take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/3gd5t58o/3/

Comment: The image is just to test. I am trying to create a header where everything that passes under it is blurred.

Comment: Ho ok sorry, you should take a look to this one so : https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/

Comment: Again it is using another image to do the trick. I have dynamic content at the bottom.